# I am pretty curious about char pointers

Tags: c

I have learned that char *p means "a pointer to char type"

and also I think I've also learned that char means to read

that amount of memory once that pointer reaches its' destination.

so conclusively, in

```
char *p = "hello World";
```

the p contains the strings' address and

the `p` is pointing right at it

Qusetions.

1. if the p points to the string, shouldn't it be reading only the 'h'???
   since it only reads the sizeof a char?
   why does `printf("%s", p) print the whole string???
2. I also learned in Rithcie's book that pointer variables don't possess a data type.
    is that true???

Comment: `printf("%s", *p)` is wrong. It should be either `printf("%s", p)` to print the whole string, or `printf("%c", *p)` to print the first character.

Comment: This is really a complex detail, and you need to get it right.  You need to study some textbooks before you go much farther.  But `anything *` in a declaration means "pointer to an `anything` entity".  So `char *` **means** "pointer to a single character".  **By convention**, since C does not have a "string" type, the meaning of `char *` is overloaded to also sometimes mean "pointer to the first character in a sequence of related characters, probably terminated by a zero byte".  But this is only a convention, it is not a part of the language.

Comment: `"char means to read ..."` - Huh? That's not right. Either your explanation or your understanding is a few steps off. A `char` is and means nothing else, other than being a `char`. And a `char*` is nothing more than a memory address of a `char`. There is no `"destination"` except maybe the null-terminator at the end of a 'string', but `char` knows nothing about this. But `printf` will loop through and find the null-terminator for `%s`.

Comment: well I'm not really concerned about the syntex errors I wrote, I just typed mindlessly while concentrating on my point and made a mistake. I know printf refers to an address type. well anyways that wasn't my point either, well still thanks for the answer, and about the second question I'm not sure if your 100% right. because according to the declaration, assuming that pointer have data types, int* a,b; it declares int *a & int b seperately which I thinkthe compiler doesn't consider the pointer as a data type

Answer (score 5):

So your string "hello world" occupies some memory.

```
[h][e][l][l][o][ ][w][o][r][l][d][\0]
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][A][B ]
```

The pointer `p` does, in fact, only point to the first byte.  In this case, byte 0.  But if you use it in the context of

`printf("%s", p)`

Then `printf` knows to print until it gets the null character `\0`, which is why it will print the entire string and not just 'h'.

As for the second question, pointers do posses a data type.  If you were to say it outloud, the name would probably be something like type "pointer to a character" in the case of `p`, or "pointer to an integer" for `int *i`.

Comment: THANKS!! I didn;t know the %s indicates "until it finds the '\0'"

Answer (score 1):

Pointer variables don't hold a data type, they hold an address. But you use a data type so you know how many bytes you'll advance on each step, when reading from memory using that pointer.

When you call `printf`, the `%s` in the expression is telling the function to start reading at the address indicated by *p (which does hold the byte value for 'h', as you said), and *stop reading when it reaches a terminating character*. That's a character that has no visual representation (you refer to it as `\0` in code). It tells the program where a string ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here *p is a pointer to some location in memory, that it assumes to be 1 byte (or char). So it points to the 'h' letter. So `p[0] or *(p+0)` will give you p. But, your string ends with invisible `\0` character, so when you use printf function it outputs all symbols, starting from the one, where *p points to and till `\0'.

And pointer is just a variable, that is able to hold some address (4, 8 or more bytes).

Answer (score 0):

For question:

> I also learned in Rithcie's book that pointer variables don't possess a data type. is that true???

Simply put, YES.

Data types in C are used to define a variable before its use. The definition of a variable will assign storage for the variable and define the type of data that will be held in the location.

C has the following basic built-in datatypes.`int,float,double,char`.

Quoting from [C Data types](http://pbpl.physics.ucla.edu/Computing/C_Tutorial/Reference_-_Data_Types/)

> `Pointer` is derived data type, each data type can have a pointer associated with. Pointers don't have a keyword, but are marked by a preceding `*` in the variable and function declaration/definition. Most compilers supplies the predefined constant NULL, which is equivalent to 0.

Answer (score 0):

> if the p points to the string, shouldn't it be reading only the 'h'???
>   since it only reads the sizeof a char? why does printf("%s", *p) print
>   the whole string???

change your `printf("%s", *p)` to `printf("%c", *p)` you see what you want. both calls the printf in different ways on the basis of format specifier i.e string(`%s`) or char(`%c`).

to print the string use `printf("%s", p);`

to print the char use `printf("%c", *p);`

---

Second Ans. : Pointers possesses a data type. that's why you used `char` *p .